# Moodle Email Function Not Working

Tags: php, moodle

Hi i want to send an email as soon as record is inserted in moodle database table, following code is not working

```
if ($recs = $ti_form->get_data()) {
    // Do something with the data, then redirect to a new page
    $lastinsertid = $DB->insert_record('suggestions', $recs);
    $toUser = 'omerzia@live.com';
    $fromUser = 'ICAN';
    $subject = 'New Suggestion Added';
    $messageText = 'New Suggestion Added';
    $sent = email_to_user($toUser, $fromUser, $subject, $messageText);
    //mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if($sent) {
      print "Email successfully sent";
    }else{
      print "There was an error sending the mail";
     }

       redirect('suggestions.php');
}
```

Above code givers error message. What could be the reason? Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: in else . There was an error sending the mail.

Comment: is the error appearing in the logs, the console, is it causing the program to crash? Is that the exact format? What setup are you using, platforms, servers, database version etc. The more information you add the more likely you are to get an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the phpdoc header for the email_to_user() function, the first 2 parameters should be user objects rather than strings.

```
* @param stdClass $user  A {@link $USER} object
* @param stdClass $from A {@link $USER} object
```

So for the to user

```
$touser = $DB->get_record('user', array('email' => 'omerzia@live.com');
```

For the from user you could use the support user

```
$fromuser = core_user::get_support_user();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Enabling Email Debugging in Moodle
>
> When developing email support in your Moodle plugin, you can make your
>   life a whole lot easier by enabling email debugging however this
>   should only be done in a development environment. The settings are all
>   in the same place you would normally go to put Moodle debugging in
>   DEVELOPER mode. Simply complete the following steps:

1. Click Site Administration > Advanced Features > Development > Debugging
2. Set Debug messages to DEVELOPER: extra Moodle debug messages for developers
3. Check the Display debug messages box.
4. Check the Debug email sending box.
5. Click Save changes at the bottom of the page.

Don't forget to go back and disable these settings when you are done debugging.

Debug your work, this will show you some outputs which it can be helpful for your problem.